# Problem with opacity in pgfplots when using pstricks package

Tags: pgfplots, pstricks, transparency

Can anyone tell me why doesn't opacity work in pgfplots when I include the package "pstricks" and how could I fix it?

See for example the code below:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

    \usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

    \usepackage{pstricks}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.1]
        \addplot[name path=f,domain=-.15:1.05,blue, draw=none] {x^2};
        \addplot[name path=g, domain=.15:1.05,blue, draw=none] {x^3}; 

        \addplot [
            fill=orange, 
            opacity=0.4
        ]
        fill between[
            of=f and g,
            soft clip={domain=0:1},
        ];

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}  

    \end{document}
```

Like this the opacity doesn't work for me, but if I remove `\usepackage{pstricks}` it works fine.

Comment: Are you compiling with XeLaTeX or LaTeX--> DVi --> PDF?

Comment: With LaTeX-->DVI-->PDF. I tried right now with XeLaTeX and it works fine also with pstricks. Thank you!

Comment: It also works if I compile LaTeX-->DVI-->PS-->PDF.

Comment: @Telemach, so can we close this question as being solved or do you need further assistance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.